# Unique entry set in the first column of all csv files under directory

Tags: bash, shell, awk, tcsh

I have a list of comma separated files under the directory. There are no headers, and unfortunately they are not even the same length for each row.

I want to find the unique entry in the first column across all files.

What's the quickest way of doing it in shell programming?

```
awk -F "," '{print $1}' *.txt | uniq
```

seems to only get uniq entries of each files. I want all files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortest is still using awk (this will print the row)

```
awk -F, '!a[$1]++' *.txt
```

to get just the first field

```
awk -F, '!a[$1]++ {print $1}' *.txt
```

Comment: It doesn't print singular elements, but whole rows on my machine (GNU Awk 3.1.5). You probably meant this `awk -F, '!a[$1]++ {print $1}' *.txt`

Comment: @chatraed yes, default is to print the row, need to add `{print $1}` to just to get the first field.

Comment: Thanks. but why does my script not work tho? `awk -F "," '{print $1}' *.txt | uniq`

Comment: @CodeNoob uniq only works on sorted lists, the duplicates need to be consecutive.  Need to insert sort between awk and uniq.